# How do I establish CAN protocol using PIC 16F877A?

Tags: pic, can-bus

I want to establish CAN protocol using PIC 16F877A. But PIC 16F877A does not have CAN TX and CAN RX ports. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Because the PIC 16877A don't have a CAN controller you need an external CAN controller and a CAN transceiver.

for example:

CAN controller: MCP2515 (connected with SPI to your PIC)

CAN transceiver: MCP2551 (connected to your CAN controller)